# Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, dynamic>

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am trying to loop through dictionary of values and then updating row of "MTables" (table Name) fields in 'QvxDataRow MakeEntry()' function through Key values of Dictionary.

i need "MTables" to contain like this

```
SlNo StudentName StudentClass
1        Daniel                4
2         Maties               4
```

but in my code i get  error for for each loop like below

```
Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<int, dynamic>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int, dynamic>
```

I need to add hardcoded value and put it into row of MTables. I have this

```
   private IEnumerable<QvxDataRow> GetApplicationDB()
        {
            Dictionary<int, dynamic> map = new Dictionary<int, dynamic>
    {
        {1, new {SlNo="1", StudentName="Daniel",StudentClass="4"}},
        {2, new {SlNo="2", StudentName="Maties",StudentClass="4"}}
    };

            foreach (Dictionary<int, string> evl in map)
            {
                yield return MakeEntry(evl, FindTable("ApplicationsStudentDB", MTables));
            }
}

        private QvxDataRow MakeEntry( evl, QvxTable table)
        {
            var row = new QvxDataRow();
            row[table.Fields[0]] = evl.SlNo;
            row[table.Fields[1]] = evl.StudentName;
            row[table.Fields[2]] = evl.StudentClass;
            return row;
        }
```

How could i do this, Please help me on this.

Comment: How could you do what? You do not outline an error in this question. You are telling us what you do in the code and then ask how you can do "it", we need an actual question to answer!

Comment: @Alfie Goodacre updated my query

Comment: This code won't compile. `MakeEntry(dynamic  evl, ...)` should get you on the way but you'll have missing StudentScore etc. Still not very clear.

Comment: It is always advisable to use var in for loop  `for(var x in y)`

Comment: @Henk Holterman sorry its updated now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because when you loop through items in a Dictionary, the item within the Dictionary is not a Dictionary, it's a KeyValuePair. You're declaring `evl` with the wrong type in the loop. Also, your dictionary contains `int` and `dynamic` types, but then you declare the loop as a pair of strings. You can't just alter the type like that. It should be:

```
foreach (KeyValuePair<int, dynamic> evl in map)
```

Comment: Or just `(var evl in ...)`

Comment: @ADyson How to put it into rows of MTables? i am getting object instance not set to an instance of an object error

Comment: @daisy on which line is this error occurring? have you paused execution and inspected the various variables to see which item is null / not set?

Comment: @ADyson  Thanks AD, i will post one more query, so that will be understandable

Comment: @ADyson I need little more help. In LIne  ' yield return MakeEntry(evl, FindTable("ApplicationsStudentDB", MTables)); ' i get error as 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string,object>' does not contain a definition for StudentName.

Comment: @daisy it sounds like you have changed the code a little bit, if your KeyValuePair is now <string, object>. It might be more straightforward to ask a new question relating to this problem and post your latest code. If you link to it here then I'll take a look.